# How to tune parameters in multi-armed bandit problem

Tags: multiarmed-bandit

Many multi-armed bandit algorithms involve some parameters, such as temperature of Boltzmann exploration, e in e-greedy, and so on.

As suggest in the paper Precup 2000 (Algorithms for the multi-armed bandit problem), different parameters have very different regrets for distributions of different arms and variance.

So my specific questions is, if we are using e-greedy, and want to use it in clinic trails, just as the authors did in their paper, how to tune the temperature parameter? I know that for online ads, we can simply have a small population just to tune the parameters, but for patients, it might be more difficult because the total sample size is much smaller.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a pretty problem-specific issue, and generally bandit papers are devoted to how to pick these terms in order to minimize regret given a certain prior. Do you have a particular problem/algorithm in mind?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've just edited the question to be more specific.